# Configuration of logback failed -- Why

Tags: java, classpath, slf4j, logback

I havenot able to use logback.xml file even if I have put it in every source folder or use `-Dlogback.configurationFile=C:\Users\dell\Documents\Corr\conf\logback.xml` as program argument or vm argument. But, it didnot work. Why?  Why?

Where should I put this file so that it will be detected?

What I have done;

logback.xml

```
<configuration> 
    <appender   name ="FileAppender"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">


        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
            <level>         INFO    </level>
            <onMatch>       ACCEPT  </onMatch>
            <onMismatch>    DENY    </onMismatch>
        </filter>

        <property file="conf/variables.properties" />

        <file>  ${HOME}/build/log/corr.log  </file>
        <rollingPolicy  class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>   
                ${HOME}/build/log/%d{yyyy/MM/dd}.%i.log 
            </fileNamePattern>

            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>   2MB </maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder>
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
            <pattern>
                %date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}
                %level{5}
                [%thread] 
                %class{0}.%method at %line 
                %msg
                %n
                %ex{full}
                %n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root   level="DEBUG">
            <appender-ref   ref="FileAppender" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

property file; variables.properties

```
HOME=C:\Users\dell\Documents\Corr
```

project hierarchy

```
Corr
  | - - src
          | - - CorrAnaly
                   | - - main.java
  | - - testSrc
  | - - build
          | - - log
  | - - bin
  | - - conf
          | - - logback.xml
          | - - variables.properties
```

Where I have put logback.xml

- directly under src folder
- directly under main class of project which is in package ( near main.java )
- directly under Corr folder

All of them have not worked. Also, I have tried to use conf folder as source folder. I have declared it as so and used it but not worked.

**Help me to figure out why logback not detect my file. What should I do so as to use Logback feature?**

Environment: Windows 7, Eclipse Indigo

**UPDATE**

To Run application, I am using;

- Eclipse Run Java Application
- ivyDe Dependency resolution

my ivy.xml file

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <configurations defaultconfmapping="runtime->compile">      
        <conf   name="compile" />
        <conf   name="test" />
        <conf   name="runtime"      
                extends="compile"   />
    </configurations>
    <dependencies>          
        <dependency org="SLF4J" name="slf4j-api-1.7.7"  rev="1.7.7"
                            conf="compile->default"/>   
        <dependency org="LOGBack"   name="logback-core-1.1.2"   rev="1.1.2" 
                            conf="runtime->default"/>
        <dependency org="SLF4J" name="slf4j-jdk14-1.7.7"    rev="1.7.7" 
                            conf="runtime->default"/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

**UPDATE 2**
I have also tried with simple logback.xml in case of my first configuration is not working. It didnot worked even for simple logback.xml case;

```
<appender   name ="ConsoleAppender" 
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">

    <encoder>   
        <charset>   UTF-8   </charset>
        <pattern>%-5level [%thread] %class{0}.%method at line %line --%message%n%ex</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<root   level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref   ref="ConsoleAppender" />
</root>
```

**UPDATE 3**

Since last night, I have tried bunch of things and lastly in source code, I can get not null result from `getClass().getResource("/logback/logback.xml").toURI().toString()`. However, still, default logback.xml is called.

bin structure

```
bin
 | - - Corr
 | - - conf
         | - - logback.xml
```

I have tried `-Dlogback.configurationFile=` in vm argument section of Eclipse ( separatly and one by one);

- \bin\logback\logback.xml
- /bin/logback/logback.xml
- bin\logback\logback.xml
- bin/logback/logback.xml
- \logback\logback.xml
- /logback/logback.xml
- logback\logback.xml
- logback/logback.xml
- \logback.xml
- /logback.xml
- logback.xml
- ~\Documents\Corr\build\logback\logback.xml
- ~/Documents/Corr/build/logback/logback.xml

**My brain: Out of mind Error; Help me!**

Comment: Is your .xml file getting copied into the bin (or target) directory? What build system are you using? It won't be on the classpath unless it's in the same directory structure as your .class files.

Comment: Also, give your full -Dlogback.configurationFile= value.

Comment: @ccleve how can I say eclipse to copy logback.xml to bin folder? No, it is not copied to bin directory.

Comment: @ccleve as build system, I am using default Eclipse run application and ivyDe dependency resolution.

Comment: First, copy the file manually and see if it works. If so, figure out how to configure your build system. I use Maven, so I don't think I can help you.

Comment: @ccleveI have put logback.xml under `main.class` without changing any statement. Not worked. Why?

Comment: You should try with a simpler config file that outputs the logs to stdout. The issue may be in logback.xml itself.

Comment: @assylias I have tried with simple logback.xml, see update. But not worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I donot know the reason behind above problem but after changing dependency file like;

```
<dependency org="SLF4J" name="slf4j-api-1.7.7"  rev="1.7.7"
            conf="compile->default"/>
<dependency org="LOGBack"   name="logback-core-1.1.2"   rev="1.1.2" 
            conf="runtime->default"/>
<dependency org="LOGBack"   name="logback-classic-1.1.2"    rev="1.1.2" 
            conf="runtime->default"/>
```

configuration file of mine has, now, recognized by Logback. I think `slf4j-jdk14-1.7.7` blocking Logback to read my configuration file.

To emphasize, I have used jdk of slf4j which caused to bind Logback to its internal and to ignore my own configuration file namely logback.xml. (I said "ignores" because you can my effort, all possibilities I have tried, at question body.)

Comment: Your problem surely was missing logback-classic and not about slf4j-jdk14-1.7.7, because classic implements lots of things needed.

Comment: @ThorstenSchöning you are wrong. I have used jdk version, and no error or warnings has occured. Log is show in form of "date error class name msg". Whenever I have tried to find which configuration file is read, I have put classic jar version in the dependency script; afterwards I took multiple binding error. After reading some  explanation in Logback website, I feel jdk block Logback to read my conf file. I think I am right.

Comment: You are right, I thought slf4j-jdk14-1.7.7 is an additional "to slf4j" binding, but it's not, it's the exact opposite, a "from slf4j to anywhere but logback" binding. That's why logback didn't work for you.

Comment: Thank you @Hevan !